# How to get plain text from an element in PrototypeJS?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

How can I get plain text from an element?

```
<div id="summary_header">
    <span class="heading" style="margin-left: 210px;">This is first line</span><br/>
    <span style="margin-left: 260px;"><b> You are in second line</b></span><br/>
</div>
```

What's the way to get plain text from this `div` tag? I want to get plain text as "This is first line You are in second line".

`$('summary_header').textContent` gives with white spaces.

Comment: Is their is any method in prototypeJs like jQuery text() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a method, no problem. That is the beauty of javascript and it's prototypal inheritance.

Prototype.js allows you to extend the Element object with new methods. 
Just add this to your scripts:

```
Element.addMethods({
    getText: function(element) {
        element = $(element);
        return element.innerHTML.strip().stripTags().replace(/\n/g,' ').replace(/\s+/g,' ');
    }
});
```

That is almost the same as @koko proposed, but I suggest changing each new line character `\n` to one space instead of removing them, and changing any number of consecutive withe-space characters to single space. This is similar behavior to what browsers do.

When you at that to your scripts, **after the prototype.js loads**, you can use new method to get plain text:

var plainText = $('summary_header').getText();

Comment: It would make sense to have the `strip` after `stripTags` since there might be extraneous whitespace inside those tags, and the two regular expressions can be collapsed into one: `/[\n\s]+/g`

Comment: Right, both of your comments make sesne. Thanks. To much inspiration by koko's code...

Answer (score 2):

It's not very beautiful, but it works. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but there you go:

```
var f = $('summary_header').innerHTML.strip().stripTags().replace(/\n/g,'').replace(/\s{2}/g,'');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8uFS/1/

Comment: I need a method like text() in jQuery to get plain text form an element. Same way as in PrototypeJS

Comment: http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/stripTags and http://www.prototypejs.org/api/string/strip